# $G$ $p$-group. If $H\triangleleft G$, then $H\cap C(G)\ne \{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I'm pretty new on this subject and I need a hint to begin to solve this question:

> If $G$ is a finite p-group, $H\triangleleft G$ and $H\ne \{e\}$, then
>   $H\cap C(G)\ne \{e\}$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess $\,C(G)=Z(G)=$ the group's center...?

Comment: Here are some hints: By induction on $|H|$ you can assume that $H$ is characterically simple, ie elementary abelian. Thus, $G$ acts on $H$ via automorphisms but $H$ can be seen as a vector space over a field of $p$ elements, and a $p$-group acting on such a vector spaces will have a non-zero fixed point (show that such a fixed point will be in that intersection)

Comment: @DonAntonio yes the group center

Comment: @BabakS. it's the group center

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft what is "elementary abelian"? I didn't study vector spaces yet (I will study it only in the next chapter)

Comment: Elementary abelian means that it is abelian and all elements have order $p$. If you are not familiar with vector spaces and the result I mentioned, I will have to try to come up with a different hint.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, thank you anyway for trying to help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This much is true for any nilpotent group, and the proof there is very simple...alas, we're going to have to go the long way with hints:

1) $\,H\,$ is a union of conjugacy classes

2) Each conjugacy class has order a power of $\,p\,$

3) Since there's for sure one conjugacy class with one single element, then *it must* be at least another conjugacy class with one single element, say $\,w\,$

4) The element $\,w\,$ is central.

Comment: Why each conjugacy class has order a power of $p$? thank you for your answer.

Comment: yes, I think I know, because of the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: Indeed, @user42912...so after all we use here some actionish stuff. :)

Comment: I tried a lot and I couldn't prove that there is one conjugacy class with one single element :(

Comment: @user42912 How does $G$ acts on the identity element?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, I proved that the orbit of $e$ has only one element (the $e$ itself), thanks.

Comment: why because of that there is another conjugacy class with only one element? there is anything to do with the fact of the sum of the order of the conjugacy classes (each has $p^î$ elements) has to be a power of $p$ (the order of $G$)?

Comment: yes, it has to do with it, I think I proved, thank you for the hints, it was really helpful!

Comment: when do you use the fact that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: In (1), of course! This point characterizes normal subgroups.

Comment: In order to have an action by conjugation from a group $G$ in its subgroup $H$, $H$ has to be normal?

Comment: Of course, @user42912, otherwise how can you be sure that $$g\in G\;,\;h\in H\;\implies h^g:=g^{-1}hg\in H\,\;\;?$$

Comment: yes, that what I thought. Thank you very much for your help, I'm really grateful.

Comment: Any time, @user42912 ....

Answer (score 2):

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation. The orbits having size $\gt 1$, must have size divisible by $p$ by orbit-stabilizer theorem. Then, the number of orbits having size $1$ must be divisible by $p$ since $H \neq 1$. But their union is $H \cap Z(G)$.

Comment: So much simpler than what I was doing.

Comment: Saying $G$ acts on H by conjugation you meant the following group action: $G\times H\to H$, $(g,h)\mapsto ghg^{-1}$?

Comment: Very nice: it's basically the same I proposed, but mine doesn't invite actions to play.

Comment: really? I didn't know that, why? aren't they equivalent definitions?

Comment: Are you sure? I've just proved that this conditions is satisfied also.

Comment: What is wrong with my proof: $(g_1g_2)\cdot x =(g_1g_2)^{-1}x(g_1g_2)=g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}xg_1g_2=g_2^{-1}(g_1\cdot x)g_2=g_2\cdot (g_1\cdot x)$?

Comment: yes, you're right! very interesting, thanks.